# bootstrap form alignment with multiple controls

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Hello all I am having my design as follows in my html

```
@model PPM.Models.ProjectModel
<div class="panel-heading panel-head">Create New Project</div>
<br />
<div class="container">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Invite", "Invite", null, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "post", LoadingElementId = "divLoading", OnSuccess = "getresult" }, null))
        {
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="ProjectName" class="col-sm-4">Project Name</label>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProjectName, "", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Project Name" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProjectName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="ManagerId" class="col-sm-4">Project Manager</label>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.ManagerId, Model.ManagerList, "--SELECT--", new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ManagerId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label for="Duration">Duration </label>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Duration, "", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Duration" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Duration, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.DurationId, Model.DurationTypes, "--SELECT--", new { @class = "form-control input-xs" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DurationId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="NoOfResources" class="col-sm-4">No Of Resources</label>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NoOfResourses, "", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Number of resources" } })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="StartDate" class="col-sm-4">Start Date</label>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate, "", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Number of resources" } })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="EndDate" class="col-sm-4">End Date</label>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EndDate, "", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Number of resources" } })
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

I am getting form as expected but I am unable to align one control inline. can some one help me. I would like to see them in one line
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you aren't using columns for the 'Duration' label so what you have is:

`<label for="Duration">Duration </label>`

When it should be:
`<label for="Duration" class="col-sm-4">Duration </label>`

like the rest of your labels.

Comment: If I made that my select is coming down to Duration

Comment: In that case, have you tried messing with Bootstrap's `row` and `col-sm-offset-x` (where x is the number of columns) to get it aligned?

Comment: I didn't get you can I have a fiddle

Comment: Sorry it took a while but [here is a link](https://jsfiddle.net/y0434pv7/23/) to one that works for what you're wanting.

Comment: I want the controls to be aligned next to each other

Comment: After duration I need to display the list